# Firefox ghost image

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop

I'm currently using a table structure with the native HTML5 Drag&Drop functionality. I'm applying some "transform" CSS to the table.

The problem here is that after applying "transform" property on the element, if I try to drag&drop via Firefox, the ghost image is positioned far of the cursor ( as I can see, on its original position).

Its working fine on Chrome and Edge, but Firefox gives this bug.

Do you know anything I can try so I can modify the position of the ghost image or fix this issue?

```
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6j3fbq17/
```

Thanks!

Comment: without any code, how do you expect anyone to tell you what you're doing wrong?

Comment: Looks fine to me in Firefox. Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Drag&drop the whole chart before trying to drag and drop the nodes

Comment: the fiddle works just fine in FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transformations are different for firefox than they are for chrome.

I haven't read your code completly, but i assume that the problem is that you forgot to add a fallback variant for mozilla.

firefox needs a special prefix, e.g. `-webkit-transform: translate(100px) rotate(20deg);`

taking a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) might help.

Comment: if this helped I'd be thankful if you could mark the answer as the solution to your problem